# URL in Address Bar not Changing for NodeJS powered website

Tags: html, node.js

I'm building a website that's entirely hosted on my own VPS using NodeJS since I don't want to pay for hosting and I already had the VPS so I figured why not use it.

The issue I'm having is whenever I click on a link from the homepage and navigate to that page, the website does exactly what it's supposed to do but the url doesn't update in the address bar.

Say my url is www.examplesite.com and when I click a link, it goes to www.examplesite.com/application. The second url isn't reflected in the address bar so when I refresh www.examplesite.com/application, because it says www.examplesite.com in the address bar of Chrome, it reloads the home page.

Is there a way to fix that via node or will I just have to suck it up and buy web hosting? I'll do it eventually but not for a while.

Comment: Put some code fron the client and thse server plz.

Comment: Can't, NDA. I'm just wondering how, when you click a link, to reflect that change in the address bar.

Comment: @shadow that's not something you have to magically enable in Node, so there's something else going on (it might also be client-side related). Without code it's rather hard to debug, perhaps you can whip up a bare bones example without breaking the NDA?

Comment: Our main page isn't ready yet so all it is a bit of javascript that says `window.location.href = new_url;'
The address bar just doesn't reflect the new url.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you never call `res.end();` in your server function?

Comment: Naw, I'm using response.sendfile() to just send the whole html file